# Angular - how to build 72 production packages faster

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

We currently build 72 production packages with every new feature:

- 6 White-label mutations (using different angular configurations for replacing css, images, components etc.)
- Every mutation has 6 language variants using i18n XLF files
- Every package has build for ES2015 and es5

All together it takes 3 hours now. What are the best options to make it faster? At this moment we execute npm run build-all, that sequentially runs one build after another. It consumes about 1GB RAM and 100% CPU.

We consider:

Build own powerful PC - what would be the best specification? Can we utilise multithread CPUs and build in parallel?

Rent super powerful AWS EC2 instance and doing stop/start for build only

Building packages in parallel using current machine - do you have example of scripts / tools?

Any other recommendation?

Comment: I think you should start with questioning yourselves about what brought you to 72 packages and how to optimize it to less - not how to build it faster.

Comment: @Dino How can you avoid separate packages if using out of the box angular i18n? How do you avoid separate ES2015 and ES5 package if you want to optimise loading? How do you avoid separate packages for white label solutions running on different domains, using different components, styles, images? Your downvoting without any advise does not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, you can leverage cloud services clubbed with CI/CD pipeline, docker containers to build the packages and which can run in parallel.

Comment: I do not have a first hand experience in using pipelines in cloud services. Is it generally more cost-efficient/faster solution than using own or dedicated machine in the cloud?

Comment: Please go through link https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/ and you pay only for the time you run the service.